# Find all nodes with defined attribute in networkx graph

Tags: python, networking, graph, networkx

I looking for a elegant way to find all nodes with a defined attribute. E.g. let's say I create a new network with two nodes

```
G.add_node('A', attr1='alpha')
G.add_node('B', attr1='beta')
```

Now, I would like to have a function that returns all nodes where the attribute "attr1" that matches "beta" something like

THX
Lazloo

Comment: What is your question? What did you try? Where is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
L = [node for node in G.nodes() if G.node[node]['attr1']=='beta']
```

to create a list (look at list comprehensions).  You can also create other data types that contain all of these nodes.